# As a result of cross-validation, the difference between the ideal auc values ​of the train set and the test set

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, overfitting

[image]

In the attached figure, the x-axis is the number features of s removed, and the y-axis is the average auc score over 10 CVs.

I want to choose the point with the highest score while avoiding overfitting points.

While looking for standards for overfitting, I found [here](https://baotramduong.medium.com/machine-learning-overfitting-vs-underfitting-96fe8b41192b)
that a 10% difference in auc score is 'overfitting' and a 1% difference is 'balanced/good fit'. Then, I realized that if the difference is more than 10% even after cross validation, overfitting can be suspected. However, what is curious is when the score difference is more than 1% and less than 10%. For example, if the difference is 5%, should you suspect overfitting? Or should we suspect overfitting when it is 9%? Or, if it is less than 10%, do we not need to suspect overfitting?

Comment: What kind of cross validation are you using and what are the sizes of the train/test data?

Comment: I used the nested cv method to evaluate how well a model generalizes on a specific data set. The folds are 10 and 5, respectively.

Comment: and data has 8,500 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, if the difference is 5%, should you suspect overfitting? Or should we suspect overfitting when it is 9%? Or, if it is less than 10%, do we not need to suspect overfitting?

There are no hard and fast rules for when overfitting has occurred.  Overfitting is more a degree than a matter of kind.  That your model has much larger AUC on the training data is ultimately unsurprising since it was ostensibly constructed to make this as large as possible.

That being said, if you find that the difference is practically relevant (a question only really you can answer since you have the context on the problem) then I would recommend regularizing the model somewhat.  This should shrink the gap between train and test further.